# C++ regex to extract substring

Tags: c++, regex, string, substring

How can I extract a substring in c++ of all the characters before a * character. For example, if I have a string

```
ASDG::DS"G*0asd}}345sdgfsdfg
```

how would I extract the portion

```
ASDG::DS"G
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly don't need a regular expression for that. Just use [`std::string::find('*')`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // raw strings require C++-11
    std::string s1 = R"(ASDG::DS"G*0asd}}345sdgfsdfg)";
    std::string s2 = s1.substr(0, s1.find('*'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your text doesn't have multiple `*` because `find` return with first `*`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#define SELECT_END_CHAR "*"

int main(){

    string text = "ASDG::DS\"G*0asd}}345sdgfsdfg";
    unsigned end_index = text.find(SELECT_END_CHAR);
    string result = text.substr (0,end_index);
    cout << result << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```