# How to extract a list of substring from a string using QT RegExp

Tags: c++, regex, qt, c++11, qt5

How to extract a list of substrings from a string using QT RegExp for example, if i have this input string `"qjkfsjkdfn 54df#Sub1#sdkf ++sdf #Sub2#q qfsdf445#Sub3#sdf"`
i want to get a list that contains `"Sub1"`, `"Sub2"` and `"Sub3"` using `"(#.+#)"` RegExp.

Comment: You better use `#[^#]+#`.

Comment: You can try [basic substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941917/c-regex-to-extract-substring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
QRegExp rx("#([^#]+)#"); // create the regular expression
string text = "qjkfsjkdfn 54df#Sub1#sdkf ++sdf #Sub2#q qfsdf445#Sub3#sdf";
int pos = 0;
while ( (pos = rx.search(text, pos)) != -1 ) // while there is a matching substring
{
     cout << rx.cap(1); // output the text captured in group 1
}
```