# How to get substring from a QString using QRegExp?

Tags: c++, qt

I have recently started to work on QT. I have some operations to do with QString. I need to get the sub string of the main string using regex matching the file path in the string.

i want something like following :

```
QString str=" My file is strored on C:\My Folder\Files\Test.txt , and i need to move it."

QRegExp rx("([a-zA-Z]:\\(?:[^\\:]+\\)*((?:[^:\\]+)\.\w+))"); //matches file path

if(str.contains(rx))
{
      Qstring path=str.substring(rx);
      QMessageBox msgBox;
      msgBox.setText(path); // where path is "C:\My Folder\Files\Test.txt" .
      msgBox.exec();
}
```

I have searched for the function which returns the sub string , but till now i haven't found it. Some functions like `left(), right(), mid()` are does some alike task but not exact. So please can anyone tell me how can i do this it.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374694/how-to-extract-a-list-of-substring-from-a-string-using-qt-regexp

Comment: Im not realy to good in  `QRegExp`, but if you add double backslashes at path, coz qt can't understand your form, you can get qstringlist with 2 items, sort it with `QStringList::sort()` and get with max lenght.  `QString str = " My file is strored on C:\\My Folder\\Files\\Test.txt , and i need to move it.";
    QRegExp rx("\\w:(\\\\[a-zA-Z]+\\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.txt");`

Comment: This way i get ("C:\My Folder\Files\Test.txt", "\Files"), first item looks like you needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for `QRegExp::capturedTexts()`.
An example from the [official documantation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#capturedTexts):

```
QRegExp rx("(\\d+)(\\s*)(cm|inch(es)?)");
int pos = rx.indexIn("Length: 36 inches");
QStringList list = rx.capturedTexts();
// list is now ("36 inches", "36", " ", "inches", "es")
```

Comment: This can no longer be used, `QRegExp` has been deprecated in ***Qt 6***, and `QRegularExpression`, does not provide these 2 methods.